# how to remove location properties[object Object] from html that made from react

Tags: reactjs, properties, location, jsx

I found that the location property created by the react application has an [object Object]. This seems a bit unusual.

I wrapped the component in withRouter (react-router). My component needs to use the history and matches, so I don't have the option to remove it in my React application component.

Please let me know if this is a bad thing and if there is a way to remove or hide it from html.

thank you.

The code as follow.

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-column w-100 position-relative" location="[object Object]" match="[object Object]"><svg stroke="currentColor"
```

Comment: can you add the relevant JSX code

Comment: I found the problem.
My JSX code has <div {...props}> ... </div> in my subcomponent,
My guess is {...props} include match property.